# Fail2ban settings after changing ssh port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, fail2ban, ip-blocking

I switched my ssh port to 22000 and I changed the  port settings in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` to specify to ban on both 22 and 22000 but when I tried failing to login 6 times, my connection was cutoff but was able to try logging in again immediately.

It appears my IP wasn't banned for an hour per the default bantime I set.

Is there something wrong with how I configured this?

```
# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = 3600

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh,22000
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Netstat output per request.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1061/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1377/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      951/rserver
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1061/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22000                :::*                    LISTEN      1377/sshd
```

Comment: did it work before changing ssh port?

Comment: Yes, when it was on 22 it was banning IPs.  Now when I purposely fail on 22000 it doesn't ban and there's nothing in the logs about it.

Comment: Also I switched the config file to maxretry = 3 and it is still allowing 6... I did restart fail2ban after changing.

Comment: Can you post the output of netstat -ntlp?

Comment: Is it because I havve ssh in the ports to ban and 22 is no longer active?

Comment: How did you restart fail2ban ? the init script doesn't make it reload the conf. try `fail2ban-client reload`

Comment: What's in your fail2ban log?

Comment: @Kwaio -- That worked!  Thanks.  I managed to ban myself ;)   I had restarted with `service fail2ban restart`.  Do you want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have seen by trying myself is that **restarting the fail2ban daemon doesn't make it reload its configuration file**. (Unlike most other daemons under linux... I don't even know how it manages to save its configuration when stopped. Temporary files I guess)

The following command will solve your problem :

```
fail2ban-client reload
```

This executable can be used to poll status and other interaction with the daemon.